# Usage of "already" and "yet"

Tags: differences, adverbs, meaning

I want to know the difference between *already* and *yet* in this example:

> I was surprised that they had **__** to decide what to do.

My answer on this question was *already* and my 
teacher marked it as a wrong answer in the test.
What's the difference between *already* and *yet* in that sentence?

Comment: One big difference is that _yet_ is a [Negative Polarity Item](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf), and _already_ isn't.

Answer (score 6):

This is rather tricky.  Had the question read:

> I was surprised that they had __ decided what to do.

then the answer would be **already**.

There's no simple answer to this question, partly because of the different ways the word ***yet*** can be used.  [**Macmillan** lists seven definitions for ***yet***](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/yet#yet_27), along with three phrasal uses.  It's one of those phrasal uses being referenced in the test question:

[image]

We could add to that list of examples:

> *I am surprised that they have yet to decide what to do*.

---

As to your question about the differences between the words, some of their meanings can be very similar.  (NOAD defines ***yet*** as *up until the present*, while defining ***already*** as *before or by now* – that's a very subtle difference!) However, other usages of the two words differ.  For example, if I said:

> Have the guests arrived yet?

that would imply that I don't know whether or not the guests have arrived.  But if I said:

> Have the guests arrived already?

that would imply that I realize the guests are at the doorstep, but I'm a bit surprised by how early they've arrived.  Why the difference?  NOAD lists this additional meaning for ***already***: *as surprisingly soon or early as this*.

There are additional ways the two words can be used, yet I can't list them all here.

Answer (score 3):

"*Already*" means something HAPPENED sooner than expected.

And in your example, the presence of the infinitive "*to decide*" eliminates the possibility of using "*already*."

If the second clause was either just a plain past or past perfect phrase, it would be possible to insert "*already*" there:

> I was surprised that they **already decided** what to do.
>
> I was surprised that they **had already decided** what to do.

"*Yet*," on the other hand, is a good fit because "*yet*" means a period UNTIL NOW. It's often used to show the speaker's expectation for something to happen:

> He hasn't arrived **yet**.
>
> We don't know **yet**.
>
> Have you eaten lunch **yet**?

And so:

> ... they had **yet** to decide what to do.

Answer (score 2):

> I was surprised that they had __ to decide what to do.

In this sentence, **yet** would indicate something that *has not happened* (i.e. they have *not* decided what to do) whereas **already** would mean the opposite (they have decided).

The sentence would have to be restructured to use **already**.

> I was surprised that they had **already** decided what to do.
>
> I was surprised that they had decided what to do **already**.

For a non-native speaker, it might be difficult to see or hear how **already** doesn't "fit" in the original sentence. One way to keep the difference in mind might be to imagine the following dialogue:

> Bob: Did it already happen?
>
> Jill: Not yet!